# Open fragment from a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have a Activity extending to FragmentActivity which has 4 fragments. I now want to open fragment2 on button click which is present in fragment1.
In short I want to switch from fragment1 to fragment 2 on button click.
My code is:
    public class SampleActivity extends FragmentActivity{

```
static ViewPager mViewPager;
PagingAdapter TabAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabAdapter = new PagingAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
}
public class PagingAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    public PagingAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i){
        case 0:         
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment2();
        case 2:
            return new Fragment3();
        case 3:
            return new Fragment4();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            return context.getString(R.string.page_tab_1);
        case 1:
            return context.getString(R.string.page_tab_2);
        case 2:
            return context.getString(R.string.page_tab_3);
        case 3:
            return context.getString(R.string.page_tab_4);
        }
        return "Fragment " + (position + 1);
    }
}

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
    Button btn_close = (Button) mydeals.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
btn_all.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Needs to open fragment2 here. 
});
}
```

I have tried shifting using id but fragment4 is opening by the below code

```
ViewPager viewpager = DealsActivity.mViewPager;  
viewpager.setCurrentItem(getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Fragment1` layout, add the attribute `android:onClick="buttonClickMethod"` in your `Button` definition. Then in your activity, add the following method :

```
public void buttonClickMethod(View v) {
    // some code to execute after button click
    // ....
    // You can open fragment 2 here, like this :
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.LAYOUT_ID_FOR_FRAGMENT2, FRAGMENT2);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Note that the name of that method is the same one defined in `android:onClick` attribute.

Comment: I don't have LAYOUT_ID_FOR_FRAGMENT2. I have separate xml files for each fragment. And wouldn't FRAGMENT2 be new FRAGMENT2()?

Comment: `LAYOUT_ID_FOR_FRAGMENT2` and `FRAGMENT2` are respectively your layout resource `id` and an instance of your `Fragment2` class. I just wanted to give you an example !